# CI and HMVC structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I’ve to make a webapp with public and administrator parts and we are two different developer teams. I’ve searched the best way to do that and I found HMVC. I accomplished to install the codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc from wiredesignz and it’s working, but I think I haven’t understood the philosophy of the folder/module structure.

If I want to create a webapp with admin and public pages referencing the same db tables (for example with the admin part can configure the general preferences, blog categories, add users, add roles… and with the public part an user can add blogs, images, ...)

It will be a good structure something like that?

- /modules/blog/ -> only blog model
- /modules/user/ -> only user model
- ...
- /modules/login/ -> login controller and pages referencing user and role modules (models)
- /modules/admin/ -> admin controller and pages referencing other modules
- /modules/public/ -> public controller and pages referencing other modules
- ...
- /modules/templates -> controller and pages for public and admin template

If I want to have more than admin or public controller, I’ve to create more modules? (modules/admin_dashboard, modules/admin_users, ...)

I hope you can help me, I’m a little bit lost :/

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice tutorials by David Connelly on youtube. He suggests '1 table - 1 module' structure. Then, you can use those module's controller's methods in other modules (like dashboards) to get or manipulate the data. This is how I understood it.